# golang docker time lib not working as usual

Tags: docker, go

I may have missed something, but on my local system, everything behaves as expected, but in the container, something seems off

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC1123, "Fri, 22 Jun 2018 13:00:00 KST")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(t.String())
    fmt.Println(t.UTC().String())
    fmt.Println(t.UTC().Equal(t))
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest

COPY main.go /go/src/test/main.go
WORKDIR /go/src/test

CMD go run main.go
```

On my local system, the output from this program is:

```
2018-06-22 13:00:00 +0900 KST
2018-06-22 04:00:00 +0000 UTC
true
```

but if I build and run it in a container I get this:

```
2018-06-22 13:00:00 +0000 KST
2018-06-22 13:00:00 +0000 UTC
true
```

which seems to be converting the timezone to UTC, but it is not changing they time so they are not equal

Comment: You're not parsing the time in a location. From the [`time.Parse` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse): "If the zone abbreviation is unknown, Parse records the time as being in a fabricated location with the given zone abbreviation and a zero offset."

Comment: This indicates that the Docker image has no (or an incomplete) time zone database installed.

Comment: @peter KST is Korean time and in the container I tried `TZ=Asia/Seoul date` and it came up with the right time. Wouldn't this suggest the timezone is known?

Comment: Yes, if you line up the local timezone with what you're trying to parse then of course it's going to work: "When parsing a time with a zone abbreviation like MST, if the zone abbreviation has a defined offset in the current location, then that offset is used." Go doesn't map timezone abbreviations to offsets in general because abbreviations are ambiguous.

Comment: So offsets should always be used instead of abbreviations?